# Stop text wrapping around css genareated content?

Tags: css

Im using CSS generated content on a list. When the list text is long enough to wrap it moves too far to the left. I want the text to stay inline with itself when it wraps.

```
<ul>
  <li>List item text</li>
  <li>List item with longer text</li>
</ul>
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
li:before {
  content: "+";
  color: red;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
ul {
  width: 120px;
}
```

[image]

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uFchG

Comment: Try checking out [this](http://css-tricks.com/multi-line-padded-text/) page for examples of multi-line padding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could slightly change your CSS so that it's a `position:aboluste;` and the `li` (parent) is a `position:relative;` then move it slightly out.

**[CodePen Example](http://codepen.io/BeatAlex/pen/cztBn)**

```
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position:relative;
}

li:before {
  content: "+";
  position:absolute;
  color: red;
  left:-15px;
}

ul {
  width: 120px;
}
```

Alternatively, you could give the `li` a `margin-left` and the `:after` `left:-npx;` so it's all still within the `li` element's boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add these two lines

```
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 1em;
  text-indent: -1em;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

add this in ul:

```
text-align:center;
```

Comment: This isn't a good solution as the container width and li text will vary.

Comment: That's what he's asking you!